# How do Bastion Remnants generate, and where should I look for them?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft, me and my friends have adventured to the Nether and used the /locate command to find a [Bastion Remnant](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bastion_Remnant). We are in the process of raiding one, but I have a question. **Is there a pattern in which Bastion Remnants generate?** Or do we have to pointlessly wander around to find another? For example, are there certain biomes they are exclusive to, so that I don’t explore areas that they cannot generate? We also found 3 chests in our bastion remnant, and I just looked it up and found that you are only supposed to find 1-2 chests. Was our bastion remnant composed of two merged remnants, or are bastion remnants supposed to have that much loot?

Comment: Wrong tagging! Ill fix it.

Comment: I fixed the tag.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were on Java! Stupid me, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you discern any pattern in this?

[image: a random scattering of colorful dots]

That's locations of bastions within ~14k x ~10k area around spawn on a random seed, as generated by [Bastion Remnant Finder](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/bastion-remnant-finder#913097107) from Chunkbase.com. The varied colors determine the type of the structure:

[image: useless description of colorful dots]

On Java, at least, there are occasional diagonal "lines" 3-4 bastions long. On Bedrock it seems the only pattern is some bald spots corresponding to Basalt Deltas, where bastions don't generate (may encroach into them from neighboring biomes though).

I don't know where you looked up the "2 chests", but bastion remnants generate as a hodge-podge of matching structures using the Jigsaw blocks, and some of them contain chests. That means the number of chest depends on your luck (or just the world seed); some structures are guaranteed to appear in certain types of bastions, so some chests are guaranteed *in these types of bastions*, others are completely random.

Comment: Thanks. I tried ChunkBase and it is incredibly useful

Comment: Also, bastions only generate more than a 384 block sphere of another bastion or a fortress, to prevent overlapping of the 2 structures